# CSS animation to fade out doesn't remain faded out when the animation finishes

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code to fade out an image.

```
.fadeOut {
    -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    -moz-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-animation: fadeout 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
    animation: fadeout 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: .9;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

And in my HTML page, I have

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/myImage.png" class="fadeOut" />
```

The fade out works (initially) but after the image has faded out it returns with full opacity.

How can I keep it with an opacity of 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `animation-fill-mode` property to `forwards`.

```
.fadeOut {
    animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
}
```

From [MDN `animation-fill-mode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> The `forwards` value will force the target to retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count.

By default, the `value` is none, which means that the animation will not apply any styles to the target before or after it is executing.

Comment: Do you know why this isn't required then when I do the fade in (code pretty much the same as fade out, just reversed numbers)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Because when you fade the element in, the last keyframe is presumably `opacity: 1`, which is already the default `opacity` of the element *prior* to the animation. Conversely, on the other hand, fading the element out will end with an opacity lower than `1`.